# Web interface pattern for associating two entities from data-sets without javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, user-interface

I am writing an ASP.Net MVC application.  I have two entities - patients and treatments - which belong to large datasets with more than a thousand of each.  The user needs to be able to easily create an association between the two - say add a treatment to a patient.  I cannot use ajax or javascript.  The list of treatments would be too large for a dropdown or listbox.  Has anyone got any nice UI ideas that would work well in asp.net mvc?  Is there any standard pattern for solving this?

Regards
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular setup, I would assume the user is already looking at a "main" screen, say patient.

I would probably use a "search engine" interface for this. To realize it, I would probably have the main page (patient) generate an iframe with a src attribute that includes the id of the patient. The search results would be paginated and would come back with checkboxes or radiobuttons in front of the items. Inside the search results would be a submit button to save the association

Comment: Yeah - I could also have an assign treatment page for a patient.  As you suggested, you can search, select and add the treatment(s).  You could keep finding and adding treatments this until you return to the patient's main screen.  As you add items, they'd be listed with links for removing the item.   What would be the main advantage of doing it with an iframe?

Comment: The iframe was meant to be able to keep the main screen with the patient data together with the search results on one page. That way, people can search and assign, and never lose the patient data out of sight. Else I think usability would be even more compromised.

Comment: I see - you can refresh the iframe without refreshing the whole page